# SetText view in a runnable not working properly

Tags: android

I want to have my runnable undate my UI every .75 second, I don't want to use AnsyTask. But the TextView is only set at the end of the for loop, any idea why?

```
...

robotWords = "........Hey hello user!!!";
        wordSize = robotWords.length();
        mHandler.postDelayed(r, 750);
    }

    private Runnable r = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            for(int i=0; i<wordSize; i++)
            {           
                robotTextView.setText("why this words only display on the textView at last operation on this for loop?");
                Log.i(TAG, robotWords.substring(0, i));
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(750);
                } catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TextView is only set at the end of the for loop because of this line `Thread.sleep(750);`

Your thread will sleep before the text is really set to your textview. I think you should call Handler.postDelayed every 750ms instead of using  `Thread.sleep(750);` or use a CountDownTimer

```
new CountDownTimer(750 * wordSize, 750) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     robotTextView.setText("why this words only display on the textView at last operation on this for loop?");
            Log.i(TAG, robotWords.substring(0, i));
 }

 public void onFinish() {         
 }
```

}.start();

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be making calls to the UI thread from another thread.
use [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

```
    new CountDownTimer(wordSize*750, 750) {

         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             robotTextView.setText("...");
         }

         public void onFinish() {

         }
    }.start();
```

Comment: realized I had the first parameter wrong for CountDownTimer, was thinking it was a ScheduledRepeatingTask xD

Answer (score 1):

**Try this, call "doStuff()" when you want the operation to take place**

```
public void doStuff() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

    for(int i=0; i<wordSize; i++) {           
        robotTextView.setText("why this words only display on the textView at last operation on this for loop?");
        Log.i(TAG, robotWords.substring(0, i));


                robotTextView.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                           robotTextView.setText("why this words only display on the textView at last operation on this for loop?");
                    }
                });

        try {
            Thread.sleep(750);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Hope this helps!